# Microsoft Excel Add-In: Not working for versions earlier than 16.0.11629

Tags: excel, typescript, office365, add-in, office-addins

This is the error message:

```
Predictable Behavior
1100.4.4.6  O365 Perpetual – Legacy (Trident/IE11)
Your offer is not working on Microsoft 365 versions earlier than 16.0.11629 on Windows 10.
While clicking on the addin login page was not displayed.
```

Even after reading the documentation about the runtime environments https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/ie-11-testing, I still don't understand how to resolve this error

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Browsers used by Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins) article Microsoft 365 application versions below 16.0.116292 use Internet Explorer 11.

Internet Explorer 11 does not support JavaScript versions later than ES5. If you want to use the syntax and features of ECMAScript 2015 or later, you have two options:

- Write your code in ECMAScript 2015 (also called ES6) or later JavaScript, or in TypeScript, and then compile your code to ES5 JavaScript using a compiler such as [babel](https://babeljs.io/) or [tsc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/index.html).
- Write in ECMAScript 2015 or later JavaScript, but also load a [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) library such as [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) that enables IE to run your code.

For more information about these options, see [Support Internet Explorer 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/support-ie-11).

Also, Internet Explorer 11 does not support some HTML5 features such as media, recording, and location. To learn more, see [Determine at runtime if the add-in is running in Internet Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/support-ie-11#determine-at-runtime-if-the-add-in-is-running-in-internet-explorer).